# Refresh on commit for materialized view

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

I have 2 base operational table `test_table1` and `test_table2` on which i have created the materialized view logs . I have created a view on top of this called `test_view1` which is a join of `test_table1` and `test_table2`. Now, I need to create a materialized view on this view `test_view1`.

I created the materialized view as `REFRESH ON COMMIT` and it got created but when i run the procedure for the incremental refresh as [per](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17749/refresh.htm#DWHSG8366%20)

`execute DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('test_mview2', 'F', '', TRUE, FALSE, 0,0,0,FALSE, FALSE);`

the materialized view is not getting updated even if any DML was applied on the base tables. But, when i run the procedure for complete refresh:

`execute DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('test_mview2', 'C', '', TRUE, FALSE, 0,0,0,FALSE, FALSE);`

it is getting updated.

How can i REFRESH ON COMMIT for this particular materialized view ?

The output of dbms_mview.explain_mview: (CApability_name --possible--msgtxt)

1. REFRESH_FAST_PCT --N-- PCT is not possible on any of the detail
   tables in the mater
2. REWRITE_FULL_TEXT_MATCH --N-- Oracle error: see RELATED_NUM and
   RELATED_TEXT for details
3. REWRITE_FULL_TEXT_MATCH --N-- query rewrite is disabled on the
   materialized view
4. REWRITE_PARTIAL_TEXT_MATCH --N-- materialized view cannot support
   any type of query rewrite
5. REWRITE_PARTIAL_TEXT_MATCH --N-- query rewrite is disabled on the
   materialized view
6. REWRITE_GENERAL --N-- materialized view cannot support any type of
   query rewrite
7. REWRITE_GENERAL --N-- the reason why the capability is disabled has
   escaped analys
8. REWRITE_GENERAL --N-- query rewrite is disabled on the materialized
   view
9. REWRITE_PCT --N-- general rewrite is not possible or PCT is not
   possible on an
10. PCT_TABLE_REWRITE --N-- Oracle error: see RELATED_NUM and
     RELATED_TEXT for details
11. PCT_TABLE_REWRITE --N-- relation is not a partitioned table
12. PCT --N--
13. REFRESH_COMPLETE --Y--
14. REFRESH_FAST --N--
15. REWRITE --N--
16. PCT_TABLE --N-- Oracle error: see RELATED_NUM and RELATED_TEXT for
     details
17. PCT_TABLE --N-- relation is not a partitioned table
18. REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_INSERT --N-- mv references PL/SQL function that
     maintains state
19. REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_ONETAB_DML --N-- see the reason why
     REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_INSERT is disabled

REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_ANY_DML     N see the reason why REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_ONETAB_DML is disabled

Comment: What result do you get from DBMS_MVIEW.EXPLAIN_MVIEW for this materialized view?

Comment: Add the output of "SELECT capability_name,  possible, SUBSTR(msgtxt,1,60) AS msgtxt FROM mv_capabilities_table" to the question.

Comment: Add it to the question, for the love of gods! Stop pasting stuff into comments like a big unreadable pile of crap!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the MV Capabilities result:

> > REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_INSERT N mv references PL/SQL function that maintains state

You have a PL/SQL function defined as part of the materialized view, or the view that it references, that is preventing fast refresh from working. My bet would be that it has a SELECT statement in it, but in any case it is not deterministic.

Comment: If a MView has to be created over a view, Where should the materialized view logs be created ?

Comment: The base tables. But the problem here is with your pl/sql function, not the view. Personally I wouldn't reference a view, I'd put the complete query in the MV. That way the MV knows that the query definition does not change between refreshes.